# Change handler expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had this idea to change the handler of a rest request in express on the fly without restarting the server. My idea was something like that

```
app.use("/test", (req,res) => {
  res.json("hello!");
})
app.use("/test", (req,res) => {
  res.json("bye!");
})
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because I always get the answer back from the first one. I think express just appends the second one to the same route, but how can I replace them.

Comment: We can't `response` two times for particular `request`, when server get request first middleware is called and the response is set that's why it is not sending second response.

Comment: well I tried to give him a proper function and replaced the function and it still didn't work. is their no why to replace the handler with another one?

Comment: Can you post the function here and what else you want in response?

Comment: I tried this ... function test(req,res) {
  res.json("hello!");
}
app.use("/test", test)
test = function(req,res) {
  res.json("bye!");
}

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is building a wrapper around your handler.

```
const handler1 = (req, res) => res.json('hello');
const handler2 = (req, res) => res.json('bye');

app.use('/test', (req, res) => {
  if(/* handler1 condition*/) return handler1(req, res);
  return handler2(req, res);
}
```